# Edit/Update Action Creator in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
export function editPost(props){
 const request = axios.put(`http://www.example.com/posts`, props) ; 

     return{
      type: EDIT_POST,
      payload: request
     }; 
    }
```

hi,, is this what a proper "Update" action should look like in Redux?

- using axios to make the request
- the type was created in another file and then imported

  Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you are stuck on? it isnt clear from the posted question?

Comment: SO is a place for answering questions, rather than just checking your work. If you're having trouble with something, then that makes a good question.

Comment: Where is the question? If you want how to do it... check Stackoverflow Documentation for React Redux

Answer (score 1):

axios is promise-based, so currently you're returning a payload that doesn't exist. Look for redux-thunk and use it in the following way:

```
actionCreator() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.put('url').then((res) => dispatch({ type: EDIT_POST, payload: res }))
  }
}
```